# Comparison of two models with different number of parameters

Tags: stochastic-processes, kalman-filter, state-space-models, numerics, stochastic-calculus

I want to compare two models, which has different number of parameters. The first model is Arbitrage free Nelson-Siegel model, which has the following equation:

$y_{t}(\tau )=X_{1,t}+X_{2,t}(\frac{1-e^{-\lambda \tau }}{\lambda \tau })+X_{3,t}(\frac{1-e^{-\lambda \tau }}{\lambda \tau }-e^{-\lambda \tau })$, where state variable $X_t$ ís assumed be a Markov process that solved the following stochastic differential equation:

$dX_t=\kappa (\theta - X_t)dt+ \Sigma dW_t$, more details here [page 4](https://www.frbsf.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/wp07-20bk.pdf).

The second model is generalized AF Nelson Siegel model, which has the following equation:

$y_{t}(\tau )=X_{1,t}+X_{2,t}(\frac{1-e^{-\lambda_1 \tau }}{\lambda_1 \tau }) +X_{3,t}(\frac{1-e^{-\lambda_2 \tau }}{\lambda_2 \tau })+X_{4,t}(\frac{1-e^{-\lambda_1 \tau }}{\lambda_1 \tau }-e^{-\lambda_1 \tau })+ X_{5,t}(\frac{1-e^{-\lambda_2 \tau }}{\lambda_2 \tau }-e^{-\lambda_2 \tau })$

where state variable $X_t$ is also assumed to be Markov process.

I used Kalman filter for estimation of parameters from both models. I can compare those two models by mean or RMSE but this comparison does not include stochastic part of the model. Is there any other method which would include stochastic part too?

My idea was to use AIC and BIC criteria.

AIC=$-2log L(\Psi )+2n$ where n denotes the number of parameters and $log L(\Psi )$ denotes the logarithm of the likelihood function evaluated at the ML estimator $\Psi $

BIC=$-2log L(\Psi )+n log T$

Can AIC and BIC be used for comparison in this case?